# Vue: beforeunload event listener is not being removed

Tags: vue.js, event-listener, removeeventlistener

I'm working on an undo delete functionality, it consist of a small modal which allows the user to undo/delay the action for a limited amount of time(similar to gmail). However, I want to ensure that the action is executed if the user decides to navigate to another window or close the tab, which I am doing like so:

```
mounted() {
  this.timeout = setTimeout(() => {
    this.close(true);
  }, this.duration);
  window.addEventListener('beforeunload', this.forceDestroyHandler, { capture: true });
},
methods: {
  close(deleteBeforeClosing) {
    if (deleteBeforeClosing) {
      clearTimeout(this.timeout);
      // This is the function dispatching to the store and deleting the item
      this.destructiveEvent(this.category, this.item.id);
    }
    this.$emit('close');
}
```

I am then (attempting) to remove the event listener on beforeDestroy:

```
beforeDestroy() {
  this.forceDestroy();
  window.removeEventListener('beforeunload', this.forceDestroyHandler, {capture: true});
},
```

However, it appears that beforeDestroy is never called, meaning the event listener is never removed - so if the user decides the close the tab or navigate, he is prompted a message even tough the undo component is not even showing anymore. If the user would click on cancel, another action would be dispatched to the store attempting to delete an already deleted item causing an server error.

I also tried to put the `removeEventListener` elsewhere but I am keep having the same issue.

Comment: why are you calling `forceDestroy` in beforeDestroy?

Comment: `forceDestroy` might not be the best name but it simply closes the modal and executes the deletion:
    `forceDestroy() {
      return this.timeout !== 0 ? this.close(true) : null;
    }, `

Comment: When you are closing the tab/window, the `beforeDestroy()` lifecycle hook on the component is never called because you're not destroying the component but the entire tab window.

Comment: Reverse the order of functions in `beforeDestroy`

Comment: @ That makes sense! But even when I `removeEventListener` in `close()` it is not being removed properly?

Comment: @UtsavPatel didn't work unfortunately.

Comment: @Terry I am now removing the event listener in `close()` and it works all of the sudden - no idea why it didn't work earlier. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To further elabourate on my comment: the reason why your `onbeforeunload` event listener is not unbound is because the `beforeDestroy()` lifecycle hook is only fired when a VueJS component is destroyed. When you close the browser tab/window, the entire thread is wiped and this does not trigger component destruction.

Since you only want to remove the listener after the modal is closed, it makes sense to do it in the `close()` method: hence why you approach worked.